# How to parse a JKS file in Node.js or what is the module?

Tags: node.js, jks

I want to parse a JKS file and compare that JKS file and the certificate to see if they are the same.

```
// server.js

fs.rename(jksPath, JKS_PATH, function(err){
  if( err ) throw err;
  console.log("success");
});

const jksFile = fs.readFileSync(JKS_PATH,"utf-8");
console.log(jksFile);
```

I even read the saved jks, but I don't know how to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two modules that can be used to parse JKS:

1. [parse-jks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-jks)
2. [jks-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jks-js)

I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for or something else????